# ASP.NET MVC Fill dropdown from Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I got a column name like `CODE` from `Projects_Table` table. How can I select all this column values with linq to dropdown. 
I tried this:

```cs
public ToolEntities db = new ToolEntities();

// GET: Projects_Table
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.list = new SelectList(db.Projects_Table, "CODE", "CODE");
    return View(db.Projects_Table.ToList());
}
```

I want to fill show this Viewbag.list like dropdown from .cshtml page.Linq does not returning the data.

Comment: Does your code throw an error? Or behaves not the way you need?

Comment: list is not filling with correct values

Comment: @kstar you should create common static function with all dropdown methods so that you can directly call that method in you're cshtml page. rather use of viewBag.

Comment: common static file will consist of all other dropdown will easily call in you're cshtml page and it will be re-usable at any page. so you should try that.

Better approach for re-usability.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill `SelectListItem` instead of `SelectList` like this

```
List<SelectListItem> projectTableList = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var projectTable in db.Projects_Table)
{
    projectTableList.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
       Text=projectTable.Code,
       Value=projectTable.ID.ToString()
     });
}
ViewBag.list = projectTableList;
return View();
```

And your view `cshtml` like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Name",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.list)
```

Comment: "ctxOdm.clsOdmWebLetterTypes" what is this